# ADFS server, proxy enabled endpoints

Tags: adfs, endpoints, proxy-server

I have a question regarding ADFS server. On ADFS server, when you click on endpoints, there are two headings proxy-enabled endpoints and enabled endpoints? I don't understand the difference between the two, can someone please explain what the difference is? I tried looking this up but can't find the difference in detail, just that a proxy enabled endpoint will become available on the internet and for security purposes you don't want to proxy enable all the endpoints? Is that right? But then which endpoints should be proxy enabled and which ones shouldn't, how can we find out?

I am new to learning about ADFS and trying to understand everything. So any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

End Points are the URL ADFS will post an assertion too.

Proxy Endpoint is the URL Web Application Proxy is configured to use.